# Bug or Feature? regular_price vs final_price in Magento2

Tags: magento2, price, special-price

I am having some weird issue in multi-store with different store currency but same base currency.

For example:

`$_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue()` gives the price in base currency.

While `$_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue()` gives price in store currency (i.e. converted value of base currency).
Even same case has been observed with `$_product->getFinalPrice()`

**Questions**:

- Is this the expected behavior?
- How to get final price value in base currency?